# How to create phase (hot) and neutral in single phase inverter?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, inverter, push-pull

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fON0AB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have made a single-phase 50 Hz-220 volts (RMS) inverters. I thought that one of the outputs will be hot and another one will be neutral. But both of the outputs are working as hot (AC tester glows).

Is there any circuit that will provide me a phase and a neutral?

**Additional information:**
1.Gate Pulse.
[image]

2. I used IRF3205 N-Channel MOSFET. (I tried power BJT too)
3. Tried various transformers. Like 12-48, 12-220, 24-48 , 220-55. This is the secondary output of a 12-220 (5A) with a 500-ohm load. The voltage has dropped because I have not implemented feedback yet. I'll do that later.
   [image]

Comment: you've made an isolated converter. So, you can just tie one of the two sides to an arbitrary potential, for example earth potential. Done.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yup. Stake it into the ground with copper, tie it to a Ufer ground (rebar in concrete slab or foundation), or lasso a nearby planet to it with a long wire and collect charges in a big bottle as the planet sweeps through space.

Comment: Will it behave the same as main power supply?

Comment: get yourself a real test tool, like a multimeter

Comment: @SadatRafi behave like main power supply in what way? this thing is an incredibly weak power supply, not voltage-regulated at all, with totally inadequate power transistors, running at 32 kHz. None of this even remotely is meant to behave like mains.

Comment: Please give us the details of your transformer. Everything else is built around it. Is it a steel or ferrite core? Dimensions?

Comment: Edited. I guess that the material of the core, core cross-sectional area has nothing to do with this question. I'll try what Muller said.

Comment: The core material and cross-section has everything to do with how it behaves.